# How are 3rd party thumbnails used without violating copyright?

Tags: web, thumbnails, reddit

For example, when I go to Reddit, they show me a bunch of thumbnails from thumbs.redditmedia.com. Presumably, they're generating these from the websites people link to. What are the status of these thumbnails? Do they violate the source's copyright? Can anyone generate them from the content of a 3rd party site? And how are they generating them i.e. do they parse the linked site to get the thumbnail, or do linked sites have an api that people can use to for thumbnail related activities?

Comment: I don't know about the legal portion (and I suspect that's off topic for SO), but [here's](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/da549027955c28b2e99098a22c814fc2ba729e11/r2/r2/lib/media.py#L634) the rough part of the thumbnail code.  It tries to use the thumbnail specified on the page itself through a `<meta>` [OGP](http://ogp.me/) tag, and if that fails it tries to use a `<link rel='image_src'>`.  If _that_ fails then it attempts to guess the best image based on size and ratios.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not a programming one (and will vary depending on your country).